# How to show other Json objects in RecylerView on Android

Tags: android, json

I want develop android application for one website. I read website posts from `json` and show its in `RecyclerView` every 10 posts.
I can show title, description and thumbnail. but i want show **medium** from **thumbnail_images** instance of **thumbnail**. I don't know how to read images from **medium** ?!

**My Json Link :**  [Link](http://tellfa.com/tafrihgah/?json=get_posts&count=10&page=1)

**AsyncTaskCodes:**

```
public class MainDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = ServerIP.getIP();

    public void getMainDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "page=1");
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<MainDataModel> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerAddress + "page=1")
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.getJSONArray("posts");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                        //get other data
                        JSONObject imageObj = postObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                        JSONObject mediumObj = imageObj.optJSONObject("medium");
                        String mediumImage = mediumObj.getString("url");
                            Log.d("Data", "Post id: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                                infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(
                                        postObject.getInt("id"),
                                        postObject.getString("title"),
                                        postObject.getString("content"),
                                        postObject.getString(mediumImage)));

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(infoModels);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for fetch **medium** image i use this code :

```
                            //get other data
                            JSONObject imageObj = postObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                            JSONObject mediumObj = imageObj.optJSONObject("medium");
                            String mediumImage = mediumObj.getString("url");
```

but when set `mediumImage` for `infoModels.add(new MainDataModel()` not show me any posts!

How can set images from **medium** ? thanks all <3

Comment: you will have to get Url for image then you can use Picasso for loading the image into image view , if you looking something like this  i can help you

Comment: @Haroon, i use `Glide` libraro for load images, can you help me? i really need this help

Comment: I can help you with Picasso , Use Picasso its straight and just 118Kb Glide is 400+ kb

Comment: @Haroon, ok man, please help me with Picasso and i change my codes with this library. thanks

Comment: below the code snip use it to load image just give it Url and initialized image view to load on ,, that it rest it will take care ..

Comment: tell me any specific if you still dont understand from below code snip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   private void setImageWithPicaso(String imageUrl) {
    if (!(imageUrl == null)) {
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imageUrl).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_background).into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                //On Success
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //On Error


            }
        });
    } else {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       //On Error
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use this code. i need read image from **medium** tag in **thumbnail_images**. but this code in not help for me :(

Comment: String mediumImage = mediumObj.getString("url"); This mediumImage  image is url to fetch from just pass this to this function